# Write french characters in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, unicode

I am trying to write french characters in python 2.7 like this:

```
plt.xlabel("Débit")
```

But, I had this error:

```
ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings
```

Is there a solution to write it please?

Comment: `plt.xlabel(u"Débit")`?

Comment: It works thank you very much.

Comment: I added it as an answer to the question @Joe

Comment: Add as first line in .py file: `# coding: utf-8`

Comment: @Mika72 That declares the encoding of the source file only, so the OP should make sure to *save* the file in UTF-8 if that declaration is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings` tells you to use a `unicode` string, so:

```
plt.xlabel(u"Débit")
```