# Using French text in Python script

Tags: python-2.7, french

I am new to Python, and I am trying to change some text from English to French in a series of ArcGIS maps, using a Python script (running version 2.7.12) and editing it in IDLE.  Following the suggestions in these posts

[Write french characters in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580918/write-french-characters-in-python-2-7)

[How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-make-the-python-interpreter-correctly-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-stri)

I used

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# coding: utf-8
```

as the first lines of my script, and included a 'u' inside the brackets before the text with the French character. However, when I make the substitution, I can no longer save or run the script.

The following code generates the English text correctly:

```
if name[0] == "Alcids":
elm_spp.text = '\r\n'.join(textwrap.wrap("Alcids: ANMU, CAAU, COMU, MAMU,     
PIGU, RHAU, UNAL",30))
```

The following does not allow me to save or run the script:

```
if name[0] == "Alcids":
elm_spp.text = '\r\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(u"Alcidés: GUCB, SCAS, GUMA,   
GMRB, GUCO, MARH, ALSP",30))
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you saving and running your script?

Comment: I am running and saving it in IDLE.